# How can I change the color of input tag in a form when focusing on it?

Tags: html, css, forms, colors, bootstrap-4

I'm creating a contact us form for my website using bootstrap, what happens is when a user clicks submit and there is a required field which is not filled, it scrolls to that field and that field has a blue border around it (this happens automatically, meaning i didn't write any code to handle empty required fields ), I want the form to act in this same behavior but the border color becomes red.

How exactly can I achieve that?

Comment: it's not the same question as those 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one class with what border style u want

```js
if ($("#frm").validationEngine('validate')) {
//add validation criteria as per your requirement

//if it is null value, addd a class to change the border color and focus it
//for exmaple suppose firstname is  the field name,
if($('#firstname').val()=="")
{
$('#firstname').addClass("required");
$('#firstname').focus();
}

}
```

```css
.required
{
border-color:red;
background:white;
}
```

```html
<form name="frm">
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="ENTER NAME">
</form>
```